# Recursion for amount of $n$-digit numbers which don't have blocks of the form $000,111,222,\dots,999$

Tags: calculus, recursion

Let $a_n$ be the amount of $n$-digit numbers which don't have blocks of the form $000,111,222,\dots,999$.

I want to find a recursion for $a_n$.

$a_n=10a_{n-1}-???$

I know I have to substract the amout of new 'invalid' numbers but I don't how to express them in terms of $a_{(.)}$

Comment: Let $b_n$ count the subset that end in two of the same digit.  Let $c_n$ count the subset that ends in two different digits.  Find recursions for $b_n$ and $c_n$ in terms of each other.

Comment: And, for $n>2$ at least, $b_n=9a_{n-2}.$